# Convergence in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, convergence, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

Hey I'm taking a deeper dive into logistic regression. Specifically the following loss function with L2 regularization,
$$l(w)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_n \log(1+\exp(-y_i \cdot x_i^Tw))+\frac{\lambda}{2}||w||^2$$
Where $y_i$ is a binary label, x and w have the same shape

After laboriously working things out, I got a Lipschitz constant of
$$\boxed{L=\frac{1}{4n}\sum_{i=1}^n||x_i||^2+\lambda}$$
I'm not sure about the 1/4 constant in front. In any case, doesn't this suggest that the smoothness is determined by the magnitude of the inputs? In such a case, if the inputs were arbitrarily large, how could GD converge if we require $\alpha L \leq 1$ for step size $\alpha$?

Further, how would I go about proving convergence for some step size $\alpha$ in SGD, given that $\alpha$ converges for GD?

Comment: the bigger the inputs, the smaller the weights, so the smaller the step size.  Typically you normalise the inputs to variance 1. (similar issue for the regularisation term)

Comment: @seanv507 How would I go about proving that in the general case, for example $\alpha = \frac{1}{4\lambda}$ converges, if at all. Thanks by the way.